Need to know how to add a already created test case to a test suite in Azure Test Plans using c# in Visual Studio
I am using REST API in C# in Visual Studio to create a test case in Azure Test Plans and after I would like to add that test case in a test suite still using C#.
Does anybody have any idea how?
Already tried this and I get this response -
The controller for path '/ProjectName/_apis/testplan/Plans/123123/suites/43243/testcases/156719' was not found or does not implement IController.
        string addToSuiteUrl = $"{azureDevOpsOrganizationUrl}{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/{testPlanId}/suites/{testSuiteId}/testcases/{testCaseId}?api-version=7.1";

        var suiteContent = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var suiteResponse = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(addToSuiteUrl), suiteContent);


refer this for Navigate Test Plans, Create manual test cases and Create test plans and test suites


Primarily, I created a test case using POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Test%20Case?api-version=7.1-preview.3 URL which has below request body.

[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "Demo Test Case"
    }
]


I will be using this test case to add to a test suite. You are getting error because you are using incorrect Url, instead use Add test cases to suite.

In order to add an existing test case to a test suite, I am using below url in C# code.


POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/suites/{suiteId}/testcases/{testCaseIds}?api-version=5.0

using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AzureDevOpsTestCase
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly string organization = "*****"; 
        private static readonly string project = "******"; 
        private static readonly int planId = 123; 
        private static readonly int suiteId = 29421; 
        private static readonly int testCaseId = 33901; 

        static async Task AddTestCaseToSuiteAsync()
        {
            var url = $"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/suites/{suiteId}/testcases/{testCaseId}?api-version=5.0";

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "Omsy***********nE=");

                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, null);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Test case added successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to add test case: {response.StatusCode}");
                    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Response: {responseContent}");
                }
            }
        }

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await AddTestCaseToSuiteAsync();
        }
    }
}



